# Countdown Timer not working and not updating UILabel

Tags: swift, timer, label

I'm trying to create a simple eggTimer, but the Timer doesn't work at all (when I print the timer to the console I get this: <__NSCFTimer: 0x60800016e4c0> ) and the countdownLabel I created is not updated at all. I'm not sure whats wrong cause I tried to follow the documentation for the timer.

Here's the code (this is for the first of three buttons softegg, mediumegg, hardegg):

```
import UIKit

var count = 0

class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet var countDownLabel: UILabel!

@IBAction func softEggButton(_ sender: Any) {

    var count = 360
    soft()
}

func soft() {

    var timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1.0, target: self, selector: #selector(ViewController.update), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

    print(timer)


}

func update() {

    if(count > 0){
        let minutes = String(count / 60)
        let seconds = String(count % 60)
        countDownLabel.text = minutes + ":" + seconds
        count -= 1
    }

}


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code you have two instances of count. The first one at the file scope and the second one in the softEggButton function. You have to remove the var in front of the count in the function. Right now you are creating a new instance and not assign it a new value. Also think about whether you really need a global variable here.

Comment: I chose the global variable because for some reason when I declare the count variable in the button function I got an error in the update() function saying: "use of an unresolved identifier". When I added the global count variable the error disappeared. Thanks btw!

Comment: That's because instances you create in functions or methods are only accessible within these. Normally you would create the count variable in the class. Just add the var count = 0 somewhere below the class statement.

Answer (score 0):

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let eggTimes = ["Soft": 5, "Medium": 7, "Hard": 12]
    var eggTime = 0
    @IBAction func pressSelected(_ sender: UIButton) {
        let hardness = sender.currentTitle!
         eggTime = eggTimes[hardness]! * 60
         Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1.0, target: self, selector: #selector(update), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

    }

    @objc func update() {

        if (eggTime > 0) {

              print("\(eggTime) seconds")

              eggTime -= 1

        }

    }
}
```